# Getting NullPointerException while using bsAdapter.getView()

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

```
public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater=cntx.getLayoutInflater();
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, null);
          //  row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow, parent, false);

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            final TextView title    =   (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
             TextView tvcol1    =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.colortext01);


            TextView gt     =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text01);


           tvcol1.setHeight(grossheight[position]);

           title.setText(datelabel[position]);


           gt.setText(df.format(grossSal[position])+" /-");

 return row;
        }
```

LogCat@

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
       at com.pawan.my2dchart1.MyChart$bsAdapter.getView(MyChart.java:109)
       at com.pawan.my2dchart1.HorizontalListView.fillListRight(HorizontalListView.java:239)
       at com.pawan.my2dchart1.HorizontalListView.fillList(HorizontalListView.java:224)
       at com.pawan.my2dchart1.HorizontalListView.onLayout(HorizontalListView.java:201)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1660)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1459)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Would be nice to know what line 109 is!

Comment: Did your simple row contain : (android.R.id.title);?

Comment: Line 109: title.setText(datelabel[position]);

Comment: did element in your layout contain id android.R.id.title?

Comment: Guys , I'm new user on this portal, but most often visit to get the solutions. Well, its the wrapper code which is expected in one of the cross-platform mobile application development framework. While Integrating the core code , faced the above mentioned error. Couldn't find the appropriate solution, because at build time it perfect , but at run time facing NullPointerException

Comment: Yes, layout does contain R.id.title

Comment: Then :  final TextView title    =   (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.title); remove final and android to be like:  TextView title    =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title), create in your layout (simplerow) textView with title id

Comment: @ user974801 even this didn't worked :( Thanks for the attempt !

Comment: clean project and rebuild it?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (convertView == null) {
            View listView = new View(c);
            LayoutInflater inflater;
            listView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simplerow,null);
        } else
            listView = (View) convertView;

         DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
         final TextView title    =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView tvcol1    =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.colortext01);
        TextView gt     =   (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text01);
        tvcol1.setHeight(grossheight[position]);
        title.setText(datelabel[position]);
        gt.setText(df.format(grossSal[position])+" /-");
        return listView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying (in the question's comments) that the `NullPointerException` occured at line `title.setText(datelabel[position]);`, there are 2 possible sources that can cause that error.

**Possible Cause 1:** The `TextView` named `title` is `null`. This can only happen in your case only if you are inflating a wrong layout (meaning a layout that does not contain a `TextView` with id `R.id.title`). So the solution would be to check if the `R.layout.simplerow` does contain the `TextView` with id `R.id.title`.

**Possible Cause 2:** The `datelabel` array maybe `null`,so make sure you initiate it properly.

Just to note, it would be a huge performance upgrade if you use the View Holder pattern in your custom `Adapter`. See [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_hoder) for more information.